# How can I fix "path for project must have only one segment" error when creating a new GWT project in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, gwt, google-plugin-eclipse

I'm using Eclipse Helios on Windows 7, with GWT SDK 2.3.  I've got a few GWT projects with that same GWT SDK. Those projects were created a couple years ago. I'm trying to create a new 'Web Application Project' (aka GWT or GAE project) and when I do so, I get the following error:

> Creation of element failed.
>
> Path for project must have only one segment.

I entered the project name and package and unchecked the GAE box. I suspect the problem lies with spaces in the GWT path, because after the 'Use default SDK' radio button it has '(gwt-2.3.0 - 2.3.0)'. If I click on 'Configure SDKs' in the GWT section, the grid inside the dialog there for the GWT SDKs has columns for Name, Version, and Location, and it looks like it is creating that (gwt-2.3.0 - 2.3.0) from the Name and Version.

I've updated the Google plugin to the latest version. I've downloaded GWT SDK 2.5 and tried using that SDK to create a project. I tried a new 'Web Application Project' with GWT unchecked and GAE checked.  All result in the same problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What project name were you trying to create?  It can't have any slashes in it.

Comment: Nothing unusual in the project name. Project name was 'MultiModules' since I'm looking into creating a GWT app with more than 1 module.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem
turned out that in my pom.xml file i did not specified artifact, see below:

```
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId></artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

In this case eclipse read the project as:

> com.example: :0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

However if you specify the artifact like below

```
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>abc</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

Eclipce will import it as

> com.example:org:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT